# Jmeter & forms authentication ticket (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, jmeter

Does anybody know if in Jmeter, using a View Results Tree node, you should see the forms authentication session cookie on the request tab?  Currently all i see is `"ASP.NET_SessionId=wha..."`, and despite logging in to the site I dont see any other cookie data.

I'm having problems ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038369/asp-net-load-testing-with-jmeter-membership-getuser-returns-null-in-httphandl)) where `Membership.GetUser()` is returning null when load testing in Jmeter, and just noticed that the authentication ticket isn't present in the cookie data.  If I use a web browser to log in I can see the forms authentication ticket using Firebug.

Could this be what's causing `Membership.GetUser()` to return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tree View does not show the cookie value (I'm looking for a source right now and will update when found).

To see the cookie, you can add a DEBUG sampler, and then view the cookie information in View Results Tree.

Not having a set cookie is probably causing the null value.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Answer (score 0):

**Sure you can!**
If you add the View Results Tree, when you stand on the request you want to check, Select the Results tab in the right window, you should see something like this:

```
GET http://YourURL.aspx

Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=<...short string...>; .ASPXAUTH=<...long string...>

Request Headers:
...
```